# Listing folders without certain file

Tags: linux

I have a 150 subfolders. Apparently 4 of them do not have files that should be in them, named PKA.dump

How can I run a command in linux to find which folders are missing the file PKA.dump?

Comment: Best idea I have atm is `find` looking for all directories which do have PKA.dump. Then the same for all directories. And compare those two files.  (`uniq` might help with the last).

Answer (score 1):

https://askubuntu.com/a/196963

Simple, it transpires. The following gets a list of directories with the cover and compares that with a list of all the second-level directories. Lines that appear in both "files" are suppressed, leaving a list of directories that need covers.

```
comm -3 \
    <(find ~/Music/ -iname 'cover.*' -printf '%h\n' | sort -u) \
    <(find ~/Music/ -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d | sort) \
| sed 's/^.*Music\///'
```

Hooray.

Notes:

- `comm`'s arguments are as follows:

  - `-1` suppress lines unique to file1
  - `-2` suppress lines unique to file2
  - `-3` suppress lines that appear in both files
- `comm` only takes files, hence the kooky `<(...)` input method. This pipes the content via a real [temporary] file.
- `comm` needs sorted input or it doesn't work and `find` does by no means guarantee an order. It also needs to be unique. The first `find` operation could find multiple files for `cover.*` so there could be duplicate entries. `sort -u` quickly ruffles those down to one. The second find is always going to be unique.
- `dirname` is a handy tool for getting a file's dir without resorting to `sed` (et al).
- `find` and `comm` are both a bit messy with their output. The final `sed` is there to clean things up so you're left with `Artist/Album`. This may or may not be desirable for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could list the folders to a file each (with `ls -1 folder | sort > file1`, etc), the run `diff` on the files. That will list you the differences between files:

Say I have 2 folders `vc` and `vc2`. I generate the lists like this:

```
ls -1 vc | sort > vc.txt
ls -1 vc2 | sort > vc2.txt
```

Then I can see the differences like this:

```
diff vc.txt vc2.txt
```

which produces:

```
< requirements.txt
```

which means that `requirements.txt` is missing (`'<'` indicates missing) from `vc2.txt` (second on the `diff` line).

Comment: How do I run diff on these files?

Comment: @JacksonHart edited the original reply with an example

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to search one level of subdirectories, I recommend a simple Bash loop:

```
for f in * ; do [ -d "$f" -a ! -e "$f/PKA.dump" ] && echo "$f" ; done
```

That is, "for all (non-hidden) entries in this directory, if it's a directory and there doesn't exist a `PKA.dump` inside, print the name of the directory".